# Bash reading tmux config?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tmux

I'm having several issues with tmux on my new account but the most bizarre one is this: what I write in my tmux configuration file is read by bash (or the terminal, whatever). My `~/.tmux.conf` is quite small:

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

This has the effect of disabling h,j,k,l in the terminal (k doesn't work like up, so I suppose it doesn't actually read the configs per se). My `.bashrc` is quite small as well (apart from the default Ubuntu stuff):

```
alias ls='ls --group-directories-first --color'
alias tmux='tmux new-session \; split-window -h\;'
source ~/dir/fileNotRelatedToThis
```

Removing the entries in `.tmux.conf` solves the problem, but I have those settings for a reason and have never experienced anything like this problem before. Anyone who can think of a real solution?

Oh and removing `.tmux.conf` does not solve the problem, so currently I don't have h,j,k,l in the terminal, hm...

edit: Rebooting enabled the letters again, phew...

Comment: Are you saying this is happening even when you are not in a tmux session?  If you're in tmux, what you describe is expected, since tmux is not sending the keystrokes through to bash at all.  (that is, bash is not ignoring them; it is never seeing them)

Comment: This happens when I'm not in a tmux session, that is correct.

Comment: `tmux` should be ignoring those keys (without the prefix, that is) as well since you aren't using the `-n` option. But, since you are using `bind` (and not the full name `bind-key`), your `.tmux.conf` is coincidentally a valid `bash` script; is there any chance you are sourcing `.tmux.conf` from `fileNotRelatedToThis` or some other configuration file?

Comment: (Although, `select-pane` isn't a valid Readline function, so those commands would just produce errors in `bah`, leaving the keys unaffected.)

Comment: When you say h, j, k, and l are disabled in the terminal do you mean you can move around with them but can't type?

Comment: Can't move around with them. "k doesn't work like up, so I suppose it doesn't actually read the configs per se"

Answer (score 0):

This will work for setting `ctrl + key_press`.

```
bind-key -n C-h select-pane -L
bind-key -n C-l select-pane -R
bind-key -n C-j select-pane -D
bind-key -n C-k select-pane -U
```

You also need to attach to the session something like this should work:

```
tmux new-session -d -n Dropdown -s Command;
tmux splitw -h -p 50 -t 0
tmux attach-session -t Command
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either. I don't know what good it would do to change from bind to bind-key etc; what I already had worked, so that's not the issue. The issue is with bash/terminal sort of reading this configuration, making h,j,k,l unusable in the terminal (outside of tmux).